# Set up Rule on Exchange Group Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, mailbox

Is it possible to set up rules on group mail boxes on an Exchange server? e.g. I would like to move e-mails from a particular address to a subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Outlook / Exchange?

I know with 2003 you can do it by starting Outlook logged in as the owner of the mailbox and setting up rules.